# Pandas Dataframe.Interpolate() gives different values for same index date

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

**Using the DataFrame**

```
date_index  value
2013-01-01  0.50
2013-01-01  0.50
2013-01-01  0.50
2013-01-01  0.50
2013-01-02  1.50
2013-01-02  1.50
2013-01-02  1.50
2013-01-02  1.50
2013-01-03  0.98
2013-01-03  0.98
2013-01-03  0.98
2013-01-03  0.98
2013-01-04  NaN
2013-01-04  1.00
2013-01-04  NaN
2013-01-04  NaN
2013-01-05  1.90
2013-01-05  1.90
2013-01-05  1.90
2013-01-05  1.90
2013-01-06  2.50
2013-01-06  2.50
2013-01-06  2.50
2013-01-06  2.50
2013-01-07  2.89
2013-01-07  2.89
2013-01-07  2.89
2013-01-07  2.89
2013-01-08  NaN
2013-01-08  NaN
2013-01-08  NaN
2013-01-08  NaN
2013-01-09  3.90
2013-01-09  3.90
2013-01-09  3.90
2013-01-09  3.90
2013-01-10  5.00
2013-01-10  5.00
2013-01-10  5.00
2013-01-10  5.00
```

**copy the above to clipboard**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df = df.set_index('date_index')
```

**Use Interpolate to fill nan's**

```
x = df.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0, limit=None, inplace=False, limit_direction='both', downcast=None)
```

I would have expected the interpolation to consider the same x point and as such y value should be same for each x.  However this is not the case.

**Dates with nan's are 2013-01-04 and 2013-01-08**

**Before**

```
2013-01-04  NaN
2013-01-04  1.00
2013-01-04  NaN
2013-01-04  NaN
2013-01-08  NaN
2013-01-08  NaN 
2013-01-08  NaN
2013-01-08  NaN
```

**After**

```
2013-01-04  0.990
2013-01-04  1.000
2013-01-04  1.300
2013-01-04  1.600
2013-01-08  3.092
2013-01-08  3.294
2013-01-08  3.496 
2013-01-08  3.698
```

**Am I understanding the use of the interpolation correctly? I expected the result of**

```
2013-01-04  1.000
2013-01-04  1.000
2013-01-04  1.000
2013-01-04  1.000
2013-01-08  3.945
2013-01-08  3.945
2013-01-08  3.945 
2013-01-08  3.945
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you may duplicated index values, and so the interpolation method thinks that these are additional steps to do the linear interpolation. So instead of going from 1 to 1.9, it goes 1 --> 1.3 --> 1.6 --> 1.9.

Here is a workaround solution that works by removing the duplicated index entries:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
uniqDates = df['date_index'].unique()
df = df.set_index('date_index')
df2 = df.dropna()
df2 = df2[-df2.index.duplicated()]
df2 = df2.reindex(uniqDates)
df2 = df2.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0, limit=None, inplace=False, limit_direction='both', downcast=None)
interpDict = df2['value'].to_dict()
df['value'] = [interpDict[x] for x in df.index]
```

**Alternatively**

You could cast the index values to datetime objects, and then use the `method='time'` interpolation:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df['date_index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_index'])
df = df.set_index('date_index')
x = df.interpolate(method='time')
x.index = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in x.index]
```

Answer (score 3):

According to documentation:

> ‘linear’: ignore the index and treat the values as equally spaced.
>   default

If you want to get the result considering the date you can select method like "time" or "index"

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Series.interpolate() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html), the `method='linear'` kwarg means that pandas will ignore the index and assume that the values are an evenly spaced series. I suggest that you turn the index into a DatetimeIndex and pass `method='time'` to the series.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
x = df.interpolate(method='time', axis=0, limit=None, inplace=False, limit_direction='both', downcast=None)
```

**After**

```
            value
date_index       
2013-01-04  1.000
2013-01-04  1.000
2013-01-04  1.000
2013-01-04  1.000
2013-01-08  3.395
2013-01-08  3.395
2013-01-08  3.395
2013-01-08  3.395
```